# Runtime type parameters

Tags: c#, generics, automapper

I'm trying to invoke a method that requires two type parameters, one of which are unknown until runtime.

```
public static TTarget Map<TSource, TTarget>(TSource source, string key) {
    var typeMapping = TypeMapper.mappings.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Key == key);
    if (typeMapping.Value == null) return null;

    Type type = Type.GetType(typeMapping.Value.ToString());
    if (type == null) return null;

    var method = typeof(Mapper).GetMethod("Map").MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TSource), type);
    return method.Invoke(source); // throws exception
}
```

I have two questions:

1. I'm using AutoMapper so `Mapper.Map<TSource, TDestination>(TSource source)` is the method that I'm trying to invoke, but when calling `method.invoke(source)` I'm getting the exception

   > Cannot resolve method invoke(TSource). **Candidates are:** object invoke(object, object[]) **or** object invoke(object, Reflection.BindingFlags, Reflection.Binder, object[], CultureInfo)

   I understand what this means but how can I invoke `Mapper.Map()` passing the argument of `TSource source` and not `object`?
2. How can I return `TTarget` instead of object which is returned by `method.Invoke()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First up: You mean, I think, a **compiler error** (happens at compile time) rather than an **exception** (happens at runtime). Setting up a repro, I get the message you quote at *compile time*.

Next, problem 1: "how can I invoke `Mapper.Map()`". As the error states, you are calling `MethodInfo.Invoke` in a way that doesn't match [any of its possible signatures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.invoke.aspx). The overload you want is the first (simpler) one.

Here, as per the docs, the *first* parameter to `Invoke`, is the object to invoke the method *on*, or, for a static method (the kind you've got here), anything you like (it's common to pass `null` to make it obvious we're invoking a static method).

The *second* parameter to `Invoke` should be an **array** of `object`, containing the parameters to pass to the method. Here the only parameter is `source`, but it still needs to go in an array.

So you need to change your call to `Invoke` to `method.Invoke(null, new object[]{source})`.

Fixing that takes us on to problem 2: "How can I return `TTarget` instead of `object`". If you're happy for type conversion errors to fail at runtime, this is as simple as a cast:

```
return (TTarget)method.Invoke(null, new object[]{source});
```

And we're done.